# Task return types gone wrong - "x has the wrong return type"

Tags: c#, .net, mono, async-await, .net-4.5

I have a line of code, that:

```
bool stop = await Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(Listen, (TcpClient) client);
```

And the corresponding task:

```
public static async Task<bool> Listen(object state)
{
    TcpClient client = (TcpClient) state;
    NetworkStream connectionStream = client.GetStream();

    IPEndPoint endPoint = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    Random randomizer = null;

    // Are we still listening?
    bool listening = true;

    // Stop the server afterwards?
    bool stop = false;

    while (listening)
    {
        int bytesRead = await connectionStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // Create a new byte array for recieved data and populate
            // with data from buffer.
            byte[] messageBytes = new byte[bytesRead];
            Array.Copy(buffer, messageBytes, messageBytes.Length);

            // Generate a message from message bytes.
            string message = encoding.GetString(messageBytes);

            switch (message)
            {
                /*
                Message handling, where one can set stop to true.
                */
            }
        }

        if (bytesRead == 0 || listening == false)
        {   
            client.Client.Dispose();
            break;
        }
    }

    return stop;
}
```

I have left major parts out of the code, as I feel they do not affect the nature of question.

So yes, when running the application, I get an error:

```
76: <..>\Program.cs(63,63): Error CS0407: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> SOQAsyncQuit.MainClass.Listen(object)' has the wrong return type (CS0407) (SOQAsyncQuit)
```

Well, I have tried to `await Task.Factory.StartNew(...)`, but then I end up with a different error:

```
76: <..>\Program.cs(35,35): Error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.StartNew(System.Action<object>, object)' and 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.StartNew<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>>(System.Func<object,System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>>, object)' (CS0121) (SOQAsyncQuit)  
76: <..>\Program.cs(57,57): Error CS0407: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> SOQAsyncQuit.MainClass.Listen(object)' has the wrong return type (CS0407) (SOQAsyncQuit)
76: <..>\Program.cs(29,29): Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'bool' (CS0029) (SOQAsyncQuit)
```

I have working `void` tasks, it's just this that I'm looking forward to transform into a typed result. Since I'm fairly new to C# and .NET in general, I'm out of clues here.

I have also been digging through: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh524395.aspx, [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537613(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537613%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), some questions on SO, though, neither of them use the `Task.Factory.StartNew` and I cannot manage to link them together.

What's is the problem here?

Comment: @MatthewWatson That is completely wrong. An async method's return type **must** be `void/Task/Task<T>` or any other awaitable.

Comment: Why is state of type `object` and not `TcpClient`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Because Task.StartNew doesn't support typed states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually with async it would be better to use `Task.Run` instead of `StartNew`. You can't if you plan on using a state object. In this case you need to "fix" the `StartNew` Usage to be:

```
bool stop = await Task<Task<bool>>.Factory.StartNew(Listen, client).Unwrap();
```

`Listen`'s return value is of `Task<bool>` and not `bool`, and so `StartNew`'s return type would need to be `Task<Task<bool>>` which you would need to await twice or use `Unwrap`. `Task.Run` was built with `async` in mind and so it does that all for you.

Comment: You can always do `Task.Run(() => Listen(client))`.